# cleaning up redundant code in an external library

Tags: c#, resharper

I am using a huge open source library in C#, but I'm only using it for a handful of specific functions. Is there a tool that I can use to automatically clean out all unused code?
I tried going about it manually using resharper but the code is so deeply nested that it is impossible...

Comment: sounds like you should create your own Library with the code that's needed otherwise, why use the `huge open source library`? why rely on something that has redundant code when you can take that functionality and add it to a smaller more manageable `CommonFunctions` Library of your own..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this: include a project containing code that calls the methods you need. Maybe this should be a unit test project. Use solution-wide analysis to remove code that is completely unused.

Then start making the public classes private. Revert this as soon as you "see red".

Also be sure to remove unused references.

If you have Ultimate, you can use a dependency diagram to give you. Visual clue about what's not used.

Comment: Thanks - you have saved me SO MUCH WORK!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no simple way to do this. In order to isolate specific methods you'll need to understand all of their dependencies and make sure those remain intact. From what you've said - which isn't enough for me to really know, this is pure speculation - you're going to have to take a lot or take nothing at all.

As recommended by DJ KRAZE, if you really only want a small subset of the functionality, make it yourself.